# Execute macro to 2nd dropdown, when click on first dropdown list

Tags: vba, excel

## Question

I have two dropdown list, is there a way to automatically select the 2nd dropdown list when I choose an option from the first dropdown list?

The dropdown list is populated using data validation by 2 pivot table.

## Code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Target
    If Not Intersect(cell, Range("F9")) Is Nothing Then
       Call Sample_Click
    ElseIf Not Intersect(cell, Range("F10")) Is Nothing Then
       Call Sample2_Click
End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

## Sample_Click

```
Dim ACount As Integer
Dim Dept As String
Dim Func As String
Dim Pos As String

Range("F9").Select
Dept = Trim(ActiveCell.Value)

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Dept").ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Dept").CurrentPage =    Dept

ACount = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").RowRange.Cells.Count
ACount = ACount + 2

Sheets("Home").Select
    Range("F10").Select
    With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=Sheet1!$A$4:$A$" & ACount
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
    End With
    ActiveCell.Formula = ""
```

## Problem

`Sample2_Click` is the same as `Sample_Click`, only difference is `Range("")` value.
I'm getting errors, despite all the effort I try.

Comment: What are the errors you are getting and what line of code is giving the error?

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to loop all cells when using intersect... also the sheet should be the correct one... this way, all you need is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Intersect(Target, [F9]) Is Nothing Then
    [F10].Select
  ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, [F10]) Is Nothing Then
    [F11].Select
  End If
End Sub
```

...worked for me without errors...

Comment: have you tried to start your `Sample_Click` with `Application.EnableEvents = False`?